# Retrieving chat history between two users sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, koa

I need help with how to retrieve chat history between two users in sequelize.

I currently have two tables; one for *users* and the other for *messages*.

My *User* table has the basic information like username, email and password while my *Message* table has information like senderId, receiverId and message

Below is the code for my models.

**Message Model**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
return queryInterface.createTable('Messages', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  receiverId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    references: {
      model: 'Users',
      key: 'id',
      as: 'receiverId',
    }
  },
  identifier: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0
  },
  senderId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    references: {
      model: 'Users',
      key: 'id',
      as: 'senderId',
    }
  },
  message: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  }
    });
   },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Messages');
   }
   };
```

**User model**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
username: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  unique: true
},
email: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
     classMethods: {
    associate: function (models) {
      // associations can be defined here
      User.hasMany(models.Message, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        foreignKey: 'senderId'
      });

      User.hasMany(models.Message, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        foreignKey: 'receiverId'
      });
        }
      }
    });
  return User;
};
```

What I need help with is how to retrieve the chat history between two users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue like this, I was able to fix it by generating a unique identifier for the two users. When user A sends a message to user B, I will combine their userId together and store in the database. e.g '234:123' then I will store it in the chat table inside the identifier column.

Something you need to understand is to make sure you store the id in ascending order. e.g if user A with an id of 3 sent a message to user B with an id of 2, when you want to store their identifier in the database, make sure you store it as '3:2' the bigger Id will come first. Whenever you want to retrieve their chat history, just use their identifier and again make sure the bigger iD comes first.

Comment: sequelize is an ORM. so what should we do if we want to load all messages of a User when user logs in?

Comment: @dealwap How did you created this unique ID? 
Did you use `belongsTo`? `belongsToMany`? 
Could you give us an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can query messages table by senderID and receiverId.
Then, if you have a lot of results maybe you can filter the query by date

Comment: Thanks for your response, what I want is to display the history. In most cases, the currently loggedIn user might be the receiver and vice-versa. How to query them with the association/JOIN is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Maybe I didnt understand, your problem is taking the username of currnt user?

Comment: Let me explain; Assuming I query the DB by receiverId there is a high chance the user is also a sender of a message to that same user. My problem is how to query the chat history between two users either if the userId is a sender or a receiver as long as it is between the other user.

Comment: You can do something like this:
where:
{
 [op.or]:[{senderID: some_id},{receiverID:some_id}]
}

Comment: Thanks, the code above will fetch where the sender/receiver is the currently loggedIn user. How about fetching the chat  to a particular user for instance; The chat message between the two of us, you can send me a message in that case, I will be the receiver and when I send you a message, you will be the receiver, I need help on how to handle an issue like that.

Comment: So put the same userid as some_id

Answer (score -1):

Don't know about Sequelize but I got the record using MySQL query, you can convert it to Sequelize

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM chats t1
WHERE (t1.senderPseudo = 'salahudin'
                 OR t1.receiverPseudo = 'salahudin') AND t1.createdAt = (SELECT MAX(t2.createdAt)
                 FROM advertz.chats t2
                 WHERE t2.senderPseudo = t1.senderPseudo)
```